# Модальное окно с просмотром картинок как в вконтакте

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, gallery, lightbox

На текущий момент я знаю, что в интернете есть большое количество jQuery плагинов для создания красивой галереи, но ни один из них (просмотренных мною) не реализует все мои требования, а именно:

- модальное окно имеет свой адрес, то есть при открытии картинки в модальном окне меняется адресная строка. И наоборот, при вводе в адресную строку ссылки на картинку происходит не просто переход на сайт, но и открытие модального окна с соответствуеющей картинкой.
- модальное окно должно содержать не только картинку, но и блоки с информацией (просмотры, дата загрузки и т.д.), теги, комментарии, лайки и любую другую информацию их базы данных, которая (информация) мне понадобится.

Лучшим примером явлется вк https://vk.com/team ну и в качестве дополнительного примера могу привести такую галерею https://dota2.ru/gallery/
В каждом из этих примеров при клике на картинку открывается модальное окно с изменением адресной строки и содержащее дополнительные блоки, помимо самого изображения.

Но чего я на текущий момент я не знаю, так это способа реаллизации этих требований даже в самых общих чертах. Устанавливал парочку относительно подходящих плагинов, но на этом всё и закончилось. Куда, как и в какую сторону нужно посмотреть, что бы приблизиться к реализации моих требований?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал Twitter Bootstrap для реализация подобного запроса.
Просто используйте GET запросы при вызове модального окна, т.е. где фотография является ссылкой с get-параметром.
Почитать про $_GET можно  [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php).
Почитать про модальные окна в Twitter Bootstrap можно [тут](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

Comment: С гет запросами разобраться не трудно, а вот что касается бутстрапа . . . что-то у меня такое ощущение, что на jQuery будет легче создать такой просмотр, хоть мне это не по зубам =) не говоря уже о том, что ещё и сам фрейворк нужно изучать

Comment: Не совсем так.
Без Bootstrap сейчас никуда, в любом случае стоит изучить(хотя бы grid - без нее уж точно никуда).
Не обязательно учить все, я же конкретно скинул ссылку на модальные окна, большего тебе и не нужно

Comment: Ага, понял, в таком случае присмотрюсь, спасибо =)

Comment: Если этот ответ вас устроил, отметьте его как правильный, чтобы остальные могли решить свою проблему аналогичную вашей